# Pass parameters in RESTAngular

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I am using angularJS, RESTangular.

I need to pass 3 parameter. 
When I an passing 1 parameter like below, I am getting data

```
subjectAllocationEdit: function (Restangular, $stateParams ) {
                                return Restangular.one('subjectAllocationEdit', $stateParams.classId).get();
                            }
```

BUT if I am passing 3 parameter like below, I am NOT getting data and even I am not able to parameters passing to my PHP end.

```
subjectAllocationEdit: function (Restangular, $stateParams ) {
                                return Restangular.one('subjectAllocationEdit', $stateParams.classId, $stateParams.sectionId, $stateParams.Type).get();
                            }
```

when hitting my api like  /http/../../subjectAllocationEdit/4/9/main    I am getting records

full state code is as below
**How I can pass 3 parameters? or what should be the alternate**

```
.state('subjectAllocationEdit', {
                        url: '/class/subjectAllocation/:classId/:sectionId/:Type',
                        templateUrl: 'app/class/html/subjectAllocation.html',
                        controller: 'subjectAllocationEditCtrl as vm',
                        resolve: {
                            subjectAllocation: function (Restangular, $stateParams) {
                                return Restangular.all('subjectAllocation').getList();
                            },
                            subjectAllocationEdit: function (Restangular, $stateParams ) {
                                return Restangular.one('subjectAllocationEdit', $stateParams.classId, $stateParams.sectionId, $stateParams.Type).get();
                            },
                        }
                    })
```

Comment: create an object and pass it as such.

Comment: like this ? but working ...  any hint    var obj = [{"classId":2,"sectionId":3,"Type":"main"}];
                                return Restangular.one('subjectAllocationEdit', $stateParams.obj).get()

Comment: `myObj = {'classId': $satateParams.classId; 'sectionId': $stateParams.sectionId; 'type':$stateParams.Type  }`

Comment: unable to get it... can you pls explain bit more

Comment: try object like this: `myObj = {$satateParams.classId, $stateParams.sectionId,  $stateParams.Type}`. I think that is what your api expects as params.

Comment: I done like this, return Restangular.one('subjectAllocationEdit' ).get($stateParams.classId, $stateParams.sectionId, $stateParams.Type); this way params are going like ?classId=1?sectionId=1?Type=main ..... instead of 1/1/main

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
subjectAllocationEdit: function (Restangular, $stateParams) {
                                return Restangular.all('subjectAllocationEdit')
                                    .getList({"classId":$stateParams.classId,"sectionId":$stateParams.sectionId,"Type":$stateParams.Type});
                            },
```